# Why are mersenne primes not wieferich primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I am a complete beginner and I am studying the relation between mersenne and wieferich primes.

Wikipedia says

> A prime divisor p of Mq, where q is prime, is a Wieferich prime if and only if $p^2$ divides Mq
>   Thus, a Mersenne prime cannot also be a Wieferich prime.

why? I understand that any two mersenne primes are always coprimes, so a mersenne prime cannot divide another mersenne prime. But I have trouble making the logical leap from that statement to the above one.

Also, the proof on mersenne primes page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers), I do not understand how

> $1 + 2^m + 2^{2m} + ... + 2^{(λ − 1)m} ≡ −λ \mod (2^m − 1)$

I apologize if I this has been asked before. But everywhere I search, the statement is given without proof.

Thank you very much :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Incomplete answer.** This statement 
$$1+2^m+2^{2m}+...+2^{(\lambda-1)m} \equiv \lambda \pmod{2^m-1}$$
is easy deductible from
$$1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^m-1} $$
$$2^m\equiv 1 \pmod{2^m-1} \tag{1}$$
by raising $(1)$ at the power of $2$
$$(2^m)^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod{2^m-1} \Rightarrow 2^{2m}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^m-1}$$
by raising $(1)$ at the power of $3$
$$(2^{m})^3 \equiv 1^3 \pmod{2^m-1} \Rightarrow 2^{3m}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^m-1}$$
$$...$$
by raising $(1)$ at the power of $\lambda -1$
$$(2^{m})^{\lambda -1} \equiv 1^{\lambda -1} \pmod{2^m-1} \Rightarrow 2^{(\lambda -1)m}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^m-1}$$
Now, we add altogether
$$1+2^m+2^{2m}+...+2^{(\lambda-1)m} \equiv 1+1+1+...+1 \equiv \lambda \pmod{2^m-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

For any prime numbers p and q, p is a prime divisor of Mq when and only when 2^q is congruent to 1 modulo p. Since q is prime and $2^{p - 1}$ is congruent to 1 modulo p, q is a factor of p - 1. p is a Weiferich prime is and only if $2^{p - 1}$ is congruent to 1 modulo $p^2$. This also happens only when $2^q$ is congruent to 1 modulo $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

rtybase has already answered the second half of the question.  The first half is quite simple:

If $M_q$ is a Mersenne prime, then it is itself a prime divisor of $M_q$.  Therefore (applying the first sentence quoted with $p = M_q$) it is a Wieferich prime iff $M_q^2$ divides $M_q$, which is clearly impossible.